# wget from matlab script - stuck threads

Tags: linux, matlab, thread-safety, wget

I need to get a set of files specified in a list from a far away server. I used a Matlab script (on Centos6 machine):

```
for k=1:length(u_list)
   o_name = fullfile(outFolder, names{k});
   i_name = u_list{k}.url;
   [status, result] = unix(['wget -O ' o_name ' ' i_name]); 
end
```

This doesn't work very well.
I'm getting lots of wget processes stuck

```
ps aux |grep wget
```

shows a lot of wget instances stuck, and some of the files don't go through. It seems to me that the trouble is with matlab not waiting for the 'system' call to return.
Any suggestions?

Edit: the urls had an excape char '&'.
Doing:
    unix(['wget -O ' o_name ' --timeout=100 "' i_name '"']);

did the trick.

Comment: It's really strange - the manual states explicitely: *The operation waits for the command to **finish** execution before returning the exit status of the command to the status variable.* What Matlab version and which wget are you using? Could it be that your names contain `&` which need escaping?

Comment: Ah, you were right. The url contained &.
I added '"' around i_name and everything works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urls had an excape char '&'. Doing:

```
unix(['wget -O ' o_name ' --timeout=100 "' i_name '"']);
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Are your wget processes just waiting for a timeout whilst the server is busy? With something as flaky as getting data from the network, I think your best bet is to acknowledge that stuff will take time, and deal with it appropriately in your code.

I would keep count of each wget process spawned, and then proceed only when everything has finished. You could do this with something like:

```
   for k=1:length(u_list)
       o_name = fullfile(outFolder, names{k});
       i_name = u_list{k}.url;
       [status, result] = unix(['echo 1 >> /tmp/Wget-Queue; wget -O ' o_name ' ' i_name '--timeout=100 && sed -i ''$s/,$//'' /tmp/Wget-Queue' ]); 
   end
```

What this does is write a one to a temporary file (call it something unique -- perhaps /tmp/$PPID/Queue would be better -- spawn off a wget process, and then delete the last character in the file when wget finishes. If the file is empty, you know your downloads are done -- you could do something simple like

```
 [~,JobsRemaining]=unix('cat /tmp/Wget-Queue'); 
 JobsRemaining=length(strfind(JobsRemaining,'1')); 

 if JobsRemaining == 0 
    doSomethingElse(); 
 end
```

to then know when to proceed.

Comment: ps aux |grep wget|wc
doesn't change for over an hour. And Matlab creates far more processes than it should. What I really need is a lock.

Comment: Or indeed pgrep wget | wc -l

Comment: _Why_ doesn't wget go away? If it's copying data over you're kind of screwed. Just write to something in /tmp and use it as a lock, which is essentially what I proposed above